# fatal error: QtGui/QApplication: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt Creator, and this line is generated automatically by the Qt Creator:

`#include <QtGui/QApplication>`

But, why am I getting this message?

`QtGui/QApplication:  No such file or directory`

Comment: Did you set the environment variable for the qt dir?

Comment: @Exa. I have added this to my `PATH`: `C:\Qt\2010.05\bin`. And, when I go to: `Tools ---> Options... ---> Qt4` in the `Qt Creator` in the `Qt versions` tab under `Auto-detected` it says `Qt in PATH <not found>`. What should I do in this case?

Comment: didn't you forget to add QT += gui into your .pro file ?

Comment: @Kamil Klimek. I have done that, but the same remains

Comment: Those are the errors that I get: `The Qt version is invalid: Could not determine the path to the binaries of the Qt installation, maybe the qmake path is wrong?` &

`The qmake command "<not found>" was not found or is not executable.`

Comment: See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html

Answer (score 21):

Depending on the Qt-version (5) QtGui was moved to QtWidgets; so it becomes

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
```

Answer (score 14):

You can try to add 'declarative' to the Project file:

```
QT += gui declarative
```

then

```
#include <QApplication>
```

It helps me

Answer (score 7):

Issue solved.

I added this to `PATH`: `C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\bin`

Instead of: `C:\Qt\2010.05\bin`

As the latter didn't contain `qmake.exe`

Answer (score 5):

This is a version problem.to fix,

- you need to add `QT += widgets` in the `.pro` file
- and run `qmake`
- and also use `#include <QApplication>` instead of `#include <QtGui/QApplication>`

Answer (score 2):

I had got same problem. From visual studio using Command Prompt(2010), I changed the path of prompt to where my Qt resides i.e. `C:\Qt`. There I set `QTDIR` environment variable.

`c:\Qt> setx QTDIR C:\Qt`

Then message was displayed:

`SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.`

Make sure VS is closed during this. When you reopen it, all headers will be detected.

I hope my solution will help anyone someday. Cheers :)