# The Qt version is invalid

Tags: c++, qt

'm trying to make a new project using `Qt Creator`, and I get the following errors when compiling:

`The Qt version is invalid: Could not determine the path to the binaries of the Qt installation, maybe the qmake path is wrong?`

`The qmake command "<not found>" was not found or is not executable.`

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the configured Qt installations under Tools->Options->Qt4

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld. I have added this to my PATH: C:\Qt\2010.05\bin. And, when I go to: Tools ---> Options... ---> Qt4 in the Qt Creator in the Qt versions tab under Auto-detected it says Qt in PATH <not found>. What should I do in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [#include <QtGui/QApplication> ---> No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535661/include-qtgui-qapplication-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved.

I added this to `PATH`: `C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\bin`

Instead of: `C:\Qt\2010.05\bin`

As that later didn't contain `qmake.exe`

Thanks.

Comment: where did you make this modification ?

Comment: This helped even though I'm on Linux (the idea that the correct path is slightly different from the auto-detected path). On Linux the path is `/usr/lib64/qt5/bin`, in case anyone else comes across this problem.