# Cannot build Qt App

Tags: visual-studio, qt, include

I recently moved a Qt application source code to a new directory (for the sake of uploading to perforce, it had to be in my workspace). Unfortunately, now I am given build errors when I try to build in VS2008 (VS2008 was what I used to build with before, anyway).

I did have some relative paths which didn't work, so I fixed those and made them absolute. However, I am being shown these errors by the VS compiler:

```
Error   30  fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtGui/QApplication': No such file or directory
Error   31  fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QMainWindow': No such file or directory
Error   32  fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QString': No such file or directory
```

And so on, for all of the standard Qt headers. I have edited my additional include directories, and there should be no more problem there. I have looked through my vcproj file... I can't figure out why this is happening at all.

Comment: It seems, that [this][1] is similar question, and there is solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535661/include-qtgui-qapplication-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: The solutions in that question don't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created the .pro file for your Qt App
If not go to Qt in the menu bar

1. Click on Create basic .pro File (Create the .pro file and save it on the same location of the project)
2. After that open the created .pro file by using Open Qt Project File(.pro) in the Qt menu.
3. Then it will ask you to replace the existing .pro File and click on yes and click on OK after that.

I think problem will be solved 
Thanks :)